# Calculate average of the printed time in a log file with Linux commands (or python)?

Tags: python, linux, command-line

I have an log file that looks like this:

```
[info] Estimate the time: 2.7s
[info] Estimate some other time: 7.9s 
[info] Estimate the time: 5.6s
[debug] variable x uninitialized
```

I would like to calculate the average time following "Estimate the time:", i this case (2.7+5.6)/2=4.15

How can I  quickly get this number with Linux commands or python? Thanks.

Comment: There's no such thing as a "Linux command". Pick a toolset for your task. For now, just stay with Python, I would suggest, because it is cleaner than most shells and also more universal.

Comment: can the time be in other units as well? minutes, hours, etc. or just seconds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a python script using regex :

```
import re

# Open the file and get the data in a string
f = open('your_log', 'r')
text = f.read()

# Use regex to find the pattern
matches = re.findall(r'Estimate the time: (\d+\.\d+)s', text)
if matches:
    times = [float(time) for time in matches] # Convert str in float
    mean = sum(times) / len(times) # Calculate the mean with built-in methods
    print(mean)
else:
    print("no data")
```

Comment: The community encourages adding explanations alongisde code, rather than purely code-based answers (see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers))

Answer (score 1):

```
sum=0
cnt=0
for log in logs:
  if "Estimate the time" in log:
    sum += extractSecondFromLog()
    cnt += 1
print(sum/cnt)
```

Comment: `sum` is built-in function, don't use it as name

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '/\[info\] Estimate the time:/ { map[cnt++]=+$5 } END { for (i in map) { cnt1++;tot=tot+map[i] } print tot/cnt1 }' logfile
```

Explanation:

```
awk '/\[info\] Estimate the time:/ {                # Process lines that contain "[info] Estimate the time:"
                 map[cnt++]=+$5                     # Create an array called map with an incrementing index and the 5th space delimited field as the value
               } 
           END {                                    # Process at the end of the file
                 for (i in map) { 
                    cnt1++;                         # Loop through the array and increment a counter with each iteration
                    tot=tot+map[i]                  # Create a running total variable
                 } 
                 print tot/cnt1                     # Print the running total divided by the count.
                }' logfile
```